# Mac open a new terminal and run a script with parameter in JAVA

Tags: java, macos, terminal, processbuilder

So I want to use ProcessBuilder in java to launch a script on a VM. That script launch an appium server and i want it to stay open even after the java program end. So i have something like this :

```
String[] command = {"/bin/sh", currentDirectory + "/Script/launchVM_Node/" + launchAppiumServer.sh, IPADRESS }; 

 ProcessBuilder   ps =new ProcessBuilder(command);
 ps.start();
```

launchAppiumServer.sh :

```
ssh username@$1 "source /etc/profile; appium serverArgs "
```

So This is working no problem, but as soon as the java program end, it close the server. So my workaround was to open a new terminal and launch the script there. Something like :

```
   String[] command = {"open -b com.apple.terminal", currentDirectory + "/Script/launchVM_Node/" + launchAppiumServer.sh, IPADRESS };
```

But it's not working. How can i open a new terminal, launch my script and pass parameter to it ? ( so at the end of my java program it won't close )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `; bash` to the end of your script. This basically tells the terminal to open a new bash shell at the end, which will stay open until you close it manually.